# How to create a REST API such as arest.io using Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I would like to create cloud service like arest.io to access MQTT broker (Mosquitto) via REST API like it is on cloud.arest.io service. The main goal is bridge between mosquitto mqtt broker and apache2 http server to getting access to sepecific mqtt topics like:

*cloud.arest.io/47fd9g/digital/5/1*

where *47fd9g/digital/5/1* means publish "digital/5/1" in "47fd9g" topic. In the http response I can get JSON data from my IoT device connected to "47fd9g" topic. If you ever used the arest arduino library and arest.io cloud, You know what I mean. I have ubuntu based server with apache, php, mosquitto, php, Mosquitto-PHP php extension. Mosquitto works fine with my IoT device but I don't know how to mosquitto and apache make  working toghether like arest.io.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number [PHP MQTT clients](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/libraries#php) that you can use to write service as you describe, but you don't directly connect apache to mosquitto. You will have to write the bridge.

But encoding data into the URL as you suggest is not going to work well, it assumes that topics are only ever a single level deep which really doesn't scale well and doesn't allow the use of wildcards.

It would be better to have a HTTP POST to http://example.com/some/multi/level/topic, with the message payload as the body of the post would publish to a the topic `some/multi/level/topic` makes a lot more sense.